# frida-discover always make traced app crash

Tags: frida

```
Process crashed: Bad access due to invalid address

***
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/sunfish/sunfish:11/RQ1A.201205.008/6943376:user/release-keys'
Revision: 'MP1.0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2022-10-05 14:55:30+0200
pid: 2921, tid: 2921, name: roid.calculator  >>> com.google.android.calculator <<<
uid: 10211
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xb8
Cause: null pointer dereference
Abort message: 'RenderThread Looper POLL_ERROR!'
    x0  0000000000000000  x1  00000071b09fb4d0  x2  0000007140772060  x3  0000007fc750e130
    x4  0000007140775d30  x5  0000000000000008  x6  53736d647543ff6f  x7  7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
    x8  5e7044044a430434  x9  0000000000080100  x10 0000000000000106  x11 0000000000000001
    x12 0000000000000000  x13 00000049ec7e2943  x14 0000510fd40fe42a  x15 00000071b09fb514
    x16 0000000000000001  x17 0000007445488ce0  x18 0000007446356000  x19 0000000000000000
    x20 0000007fc750e4d0  x21 0000000000000000  x22 000000000000003f  x23 0000000000000001
    x24 000000007fffffff  x25 00000074460d3000  x26 b4000071f0aa5e50  x27 00000000708779e8
    x28 b400007320a82be0  x29 0000007fc750e160
    lr  00000071b09fb4d4  sp  0000007fc750e130  pc  000000719dfbf264  pst 0000000080000000
backtrace:
      #00 pc 0000000000018264  <anonymous:719dfa7000>
      #01 pc 00000000006684d0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so!libart.so (offset 0x668000) (art::JniMethodEnd(unsigned int, art::Thread*)+28) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
      #02 pc 00000000006684d0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so!libart.so (offset 0x668000) (art::JniMethodEnd(unsigned int, art::Thread*)+28) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
      #03 pc 000000000020faec  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat!boot-framework.oat (offset 0x20f000) (art_jni_trampoline+156) (BuildId: c069840a4da062c0cadf31a17c8446ba32b380d8)
      #04 pc 000000000063dbc0  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat!boot-framework.oat (offset 0x63d000) (android.os.MessageQueue.next+192) (BuildId: c069840a4da062c0cadf31a17c8446ba32b380d8)
      #05 pc 000000000063a678  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat!boot-framework.oat (offset 0x211000) (android.os.Looper.loop+744) (BuildId: c069840a4da062c0cadf31a17c8446ba32b380d8)
      #06 pc 00000000003fbf90  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat!boot-framework.oat (offset 0x211000) (android.app.ActivityThread.main+752) (BuildId: c069840a4da062c0cadf31a17c8446ba32b380d8)
      #07 pc 00000000001337e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so!libart.so (offset 0x133000) (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
      #08 pc 00000000001a8a94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so!libart.so (offset 0x1a6000) (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+228) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
      #09 pc 000000000055431c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so!libart.so (offset 0x49f000) (art::InvokeMethod(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned long)+1364) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
      #10 pc 00000000004d3b28  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so!libart.so (offset 0x49f000) (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+52) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
      #11 pc 00000000000896f4  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot.oat (art_jni_trampoline+180) (BuildId: ceb5e62f6d91c45ea99526daec5879eba39c6a54)
      #12 pc 000000000088e588  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat!boot-framework.oat (offset 0x63f000) (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+136) (BuildId: c069840a4da062c0cadf31a17c8446ba32b380d8)
      #13 pc 0000000000896cb8  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat!boot-framework.oat (offset 0x63f000) (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+2280) (BuildId: c069840a4da062c0cadf31a17c8446ba32b380d8)
      #14 pc 00000000001337e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so!libart.so (offset 0x133000) (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
      #15 pc 00000000001a8a94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so!libart.so (offset 0x1a6000) (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+228) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
      #16 pc 0000000000552d58  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so!libart.so (offset 0x49f000) (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, std::__va_list)+448) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
      #17 pc 000000000055320c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so!libart.so (offset 0x49f000) (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<_jmethodID*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+92) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
      #18 pc 000000000043811c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so!libart.so (offset 0x1f4000) (art::JNI<true>::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+656) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
      #19 pc 0000000000099424  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+124) (BuildId: 8511fb98bccbbe26c39afaafc8b62b8f)
      #20 pc 00000000000a08b0  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+836) (BuildId: 8511fb98bccbbe26c39afaafc8b62b8f)
      #21 pc 0000000000003580  /system/bin/app_process64 (main+1336) (BuildId: bdcc463a75a1be87eb0f7478ec16547d)
      #22 pc 000000000004988c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so!libc.so (offset 0x42000) (__libc_init+108) (BuildId: 95f68a34fdf7b31f42d3f811d5d88f58)
***
Stopping...
```

I'm simply trying to trace the calculator app.

I'm using a Google Pixel 4a (Android 11) with Magisk (v25.2) and MagiskFrida (v15.2.2-1). I tried to do the same thing on my ONEPLUS A5000 (Android 9) with Magisk (v22.0) and MagiskFrida (v15.1.14-1) and everything worked fine.

Does anyone know why this error keeps occurring?

Comment: If it works on one phone with an older Frida version but fails on a newer phone with a newer Frida version it could be the phone or the Frida version. I would recommend to disable MagsikFrida and instead copy and run an older version of Frida Server for arm64 on the Pixel 4a and see if it works. If it works you have encountered a bug in Frida.

Comment: @Robert to be precise, it almost works on the other phone. Sometimes, when a calculator button is pressed, the app crashes and the same error posted here pops out.

Comment: i encountered a similar bug in frida version 15.2.2 try using frida version 14.2.13 it should work